# How Would I Subscribe or Get Err from Service?

Tags: angular

This is my call chain: page/component --> svc --> a remote API

page calls svc

```
this.toSVC.addData(...);
```

svc uses HttpClient who returns an Observable, so

```
addData(...)
{
    ...
    return this.http.request(req)
        .subscribe(something =>
            {}, 
            err => {console.log(err);}
            );
}
```

How would this svc tell page if a remote API call is good or bad so the page will either continue or show an error message?

If I create an Observable on the above function and page subscribes to it, NG will complain. If I move the `.subscribe` from svc to page, test shows the page won't wait and not getting any error back so always goes on to the successful side.

Potentially svc could be divided into several mini-svc, calling chain will be page -> svc1 -> ... -> svc5 -> a remote API. So how to propagate OK and BAD messages/subscriptions down?

Comment: You should be able to just `return this.http.request(req);` and in your page do `this.toSVC.addData(...).subscribe(resp => /* do something */, err => /* do something else */)`. I've done that for years and never had an issue... Can you show what complaint Angular is giving you or what you mean by "the page won't wait"? `request` is async, so you are going to have to wait for it to succeed or fail...

Comment: @HereticMonkey svc: `addData(...){ return this.http.request(req) }` page: `this.toSVC.addData(...).subscribe( resp => { this.myrouter.navigate(['Home'])}, err => {console.log(err);} );` debug shows page continues to `resp => { this.myrouter.navigate(['Home'])}'` right after `this.toSVC.addData()`, without waiting. When err returns it's already navigated to home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culprit found, I was using `.http.request(reqObj)` without any options. Its return is `HttpEvents`. I'm supposed to use Action Verb (Get/Post/Put/Delete) right after `.http` for typical API calls. It works as expected after switching over to action verbs.